# Where can I find the 'project name' in the openERP database?

Tags: postgresql, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have access to the database using postgreSQL. There are over 300 tables to look through, and I can't seem to find where to get the project name for a query I want to run. In 'project_task' there is a 'task_name' field. In 'project_phase' there is a 'phase_name' field. But in 'project_project' there doesn't seem to be a 'project_name' field. Seems a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

project_project does not have a name field.  Instead it uses inheritance at the ORM level to get a name from account_analytic_account.

Using SQL, your query will need to join project_project to account_analytic_account using analytic_account_id and get the name field off that table.